# Managing users view profiles system and passing the id to view profile page to display correct avatar image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, view, profile

Im trying to set up user environment system. I have home.php page which is a profile page and planet_search.php which displays all users with ability to view their profiles. I'm struggling on passing the id variable to home.php, so I can show correct avatar image.Here the part of home.php that displays avatar image:

```
<img class='ima'src="<?php 
                  $id = $_SESSION['id']; 
                  $query = "SELECT avatar_url FROM users WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
                  if(isset($_POST['id'])){$idu = $_POST['id'];
                    "SELECT avatar_url FROM users WHERE id = '$idu' LIMIT 1";}
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                  if(!$row["avatar_url"]){echo 'img/profile3.png';}else{echo  $row["avatar_url"];}

              ?>" alt="face"  >
```

And here is JQuery from planet_search.php:
   $(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.square').on('click', function(){
  $this_id = $(this).find('.id_user').text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",

    url: "home.php",

    data: { id: $this_id }, // or the string: 'id=1'
    complete:
    function () {
        window.location = "home.php";
    }

   });
   })
   });
```

BUt it doesnt work? it doesnt pass the variable because the

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
```

is never true. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code instead.

```
<?php 
$idu = null;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $idu = $_GET['id'];
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $idu = $_SESSION['id'];
}

$avatar_url = "img/profile3.png";

if (!is_null($idu)) {
    $query = "SELECT avatar_url FROM users WHERE id = '$idu' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($row["avatar_url"]) {
        $avatar_url = $row["avatar_url"];
    }
}

?>

<img class='ima' src="<?php echo $avatar_url; ?>" alt="face">
```

and JS:

```
$('.square').on('click', function () {
    $this_id = $(this).find('.id_user').text();

    if ($this_id != "") {
        window.location = "home.php?id=" + $this_id;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't start a session, `session_start();`

Comment: where exactelly? I include common.php to all files where session_start() is!

Comment: whene ever you want to use a $_SESSION you need to start it first,
test1.php=> `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION["var1"]="hello"; ?>`
test2php=> `<?php session_start();  echo $_SESSION["var1"];//hello ?>`